# What is a morphism of ∞-sites?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, ct.category-theory, homotopy-theory, sheaf-theory, sites

Recall that a morphism of [sites](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/site)
is a [covering-flat functor](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/flat+functor#SiteValuedFunctors)
that preserves covering families.

Morphisms of sites can be identified with those
[geometric morphisms](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/geometric+morphism) of induced toposes
for which the inverse image functor preserves representables.

If both sites have finite limits, then covering-flat functors are precisely the functors that preserve finite limits.

What is the analogue of this story for [∞-sites](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/(infinity,1)-site)?

Again, we want to identify morphisms of ∞-sites with those
geometric morphisms of induced (nonhypercompleted) ∞-toposes
for which the inverse image functor preserves representables.

Thus, a morphism of ∞-sites should be a functor between the underlying ∞-categories
that preserves covering families and satisfies the appropriate ∞-analogue of being a covering-flat functor.

**What is a covering-flat functor between ∞-sites?**

If both ∞-sites admit finite ∞-limits, then covering-flat functors could be defined
as finite ∞-limit preserving functors.

However, I am interested in ∞-sites that do not have finite ∞-limits,
such as the site of smooth manifolds or the site of [cartesian spaces](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/CartSp).

Comment: I havn't really thought about it, but you might get two different answer depending if you use site to represente hypercomplete $\infty$-topos or topological localization of presheaves categories...

Comment: @SimonHenry: The toposes in this question are not hypercompleted, although an answer in the hypercompleted case would also be interesting.

Comment: the appendix of this paper develops some of this theory (but maybe not in the generality you wanted?): https://arxiv.org/abs/1803.01804

Comment: @DylanWilson: Definition A.10 of morphisms of ∞-sites in this paper assumes the existence of pullbacks, i.e., finite ∞-limits.  Also, Proposition A.13 constructs geometric morphisms of ∞-toposes under a rather strong additional assumption of a covering lifting property.

Comment: @DmitriPavlov that's why I said it might not be the generality you want. but not *all* pullbacks are assumed, only pullbacks along covers. so the site of smooth manifolds is okay here, right? anyway, I agree the theory in that appendix is probably not quite what you want, and only mention it because I thought it may still be helpful.